# Erlang: NIFs and dialyzer warning

Tags: erlang, dialyzer, erlang-nif

When implementing NIFs, Dialyzer gives me

> Function crc16/1 has no local return

probably because I do **exit** in the .erl module (like the official docs recommend):

```
-module(my_nifs).
-export([crc16/1]).

-on_load(init/0).

init() ->
    ok = erlang:load_nif("../nifs/my_nifs", 0).

-spec crc16(_Binary :: binary()) -> non_neg_integer().
crc16(_Binary) ->
    exit(nif_library_not_loaded).
...
```

And generally, it seems that using `exit/1` always makes Dialyzer to complain with this message (`-spec .. -> no_return()` doesn't help).

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`erlang:nif_error/1/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#nif_error-1) which where created just for that.